# Can I drag and drop a file from a Tkinter GUI to an arbitrary location on my computer?

Tags: python, tkinter, drag-and-drop

I've been able to find plenty of examples online for dragging external files into a Tkinter GUI (using TkinterDnD2), but nothing about going the other way. Is it possible, for example, to drag a widget corresponding to a file's path from a Tkinter GUI to my desktop or another app and have the file moved or copied from its original location to the new location?